# ¿Cómo configuro el Sublime Text para que se ejecute con Python 2 y 3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, sublimetext3

Tengo instalado el Python 2 y 3 pero al hacer Ctrl + B (Build) por defecto usa el Python 2, quisiera cambiar para que pueda ejecutarse con Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

Vas a Tools > Build System > New Build System y dentro y lo configuras así:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

Espero que te haya servido! Saludos

Comment: Gracias por responder =). 
Pero haciendo lo que dices me sale "No Build System", coloqué
{
  "cmd": ["C:\Python35\python.exe", "$file"], 
  "selector": "source.python", 
  "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}

Psd: Disculpa por copiar y pegar el comentario que hice de la respuesta anterior.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear tu propio "Build System",

Tools -> Build System -> New Build System

```
{
  "cmd": ["ruta/python/version3", "$file"], 
  "selector": "source.python", 
  "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}
```

Debes cambiar la ruta a `python3`, si no sabes dónde está puedes poner `which python3` en la terminal y te mostrará dónde se encuentra python (En el caso de mac y linux).

Una vez hayas puesto la ruta a `python3` solo te queda ponerle un nombre a tu "Build System" y guardarlo. Aparecerá aquí:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias por responder =). 
Pero haciendo lo que dices me sale "No Build System", coloqué
{
  "cmd": ["C:\Python35\python.exe", "$file"], 
  "selector": "source.python", 
  "file_regex": "file \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]+)"
}